# How to export mxGraph flowchart in XML?

Tags: xml, mxgraph

[image]

I downloaded their library, but can not figure out how to export my painted things in xml

After clicking on the button export I have thrown back to localhost: 8090, back to the demo

How can I export? The documentation did not find the exact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
var encoder = new mxCodec();
var node = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());
mxUtils.popup(mxUtils.getPrettyXml(node), true);
```